# Why NHibernate's interface IQueryOver<T>'s method "Where" available in one context, but in other's not?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

Here is the first situation

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.QueryOver<T>().Where() // all ok

    }
}
```

Here is the same interface but in other class

```
productRepository.ExecuteQuery(over =>
{
    IQueryOver<Product> inOtherContext = over;
    inOtherContext.Where // where method not exists
});
```

I'm sure there's no problem with namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here would be to use a bit different interface

```
IQueryOver<Product, Product>
```

For example, we can see how it works in the doc of the [16.5. Aliases](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-aliases):

```
Cat catAlias = null;

IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
    ....
```

Check the [source code here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/IQueryOver.cs#L177)

```
/// <summary>
/// QueryOver&lt;TRoot,TSubType&gt; is an API for retrieving entities by composing
/// <see cref="Criterion.Expression" /> objects expressed using Lambda expression syntax
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <code>
/// IList&lt;Cat&gt; cats = session.QueryOver&lt;Cat&gt;()
///     .Where( c =&gt; c.Name == "Tigger" )
///     .And( c =&gt; c.Weight > minWeight ) )
///     .List();
/// </code>
/// </remarks>
public interface IQueryOver<TRoot,TSubType> : IQueryOver<TRoot>
{
   ...
```

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow, sir! Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)

Comment: Welcome then, enjoy SO :)